# how to fill the missing with max value by ID

Tags: r

I have data.frame that looks like this:

I would like to fille `High` with the max value for each ID. How should i do it?

[image]

I tried `result<- unlist(lapply(split(df,df$ID), function(x)  x$high= cummax(x$high)))` and it don't work.
I would like to know how you guys deal with it and if it possible, what did I do wrong. Many thanks.
Sample data can be build using

```
df<-structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3), High = c(25, 
36, 75, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), weight = c(38, 58, 36, 69, 58, 
35, 65, 24, 15), date = c(1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2)), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest the use of `mutate()` and the set of `na.rm=T` inside of `max()` function, as your `df` has some `NA` rows.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
   dplyr::group_by(ID) %>%
   dplyr::mutate(High = max(High, na.rm=T))
```

Console output:

```
#   ID  High weight  date
#  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1    25     38     1
#2     2    36     58     1
#3     3    75     36     1
#4     1    25     69     3
#5     2    36     58     3
#6     3    75     35     3
#7     1    25     65     2
#8     2    36     24     2
#9     3    75     15     2
```

Comment: `high` needs to be max(high) by ID.

Answer (score 1):

With `base R`

```
 with(df, ave(High, ID, FUN = function(x) max(x, na.rm = TRUE)))
 #[1] 25 36 75 25 36 75 25 36 75
```